# Designing a database for project

Tags: database

So I am making something similar to a project management tool.  To start with there will be a client.

```
Client
id  int(10) auto increment PK
clientName  varchar(255)
clientStatus    varchar(255)
businessUnit    varchar(255)
isDeleted   boolean
created_at  timestamp
updated_at  timestamp
```

A Client can then have contacts within their company, so I was thinking about a Client_Contact table.

```
Client_Contact
id  int(10) auto increment PK
contactName varchar(255)
contactEmail    varchar(255)
contactPhone    varchar(255)
isDeleted   boolean
created_at  timestamp
updated_at  timestamp
client_id   int(10) FK(client_id reference ‘Client’ (‘id’))
```

So when I start using the app, I firstly create a client (if they do not already exist) and their contact/s.
With a Client in place, I then need to create a Project for this Client.  A Client can have one to many projects.
This is where I am slightly stuck.  A Project consists of several things, not all of them need doing but the option to do them should be there.  Firstly, a Project starts by completing a Project Identification document.  This form should consist of the following:

```
Project_Identification
id  int(10) auto increment PK
clientName  varchar(255) (should be linked to a Client)
projectInformation  text()
projectStartDate    datetime
projectDeliveryDate datetime
isDeleted   boolean
created_at  timestamp
updated_at  timestamp
```

Once the above form has been completed, a Project Brief document needs to be completed.  The Project Brief should consist of

```
Project_Brief
id  int(10) auto increment PK
clientName  varchar(255) (should be linked to a Client)
project_id  int(10) (should be linked to Project)
projectRoles    text()
projectData text()
isDeleted   boolean
created_at  timestamp
updated_at  timestamp
```

Finally, once a Project Brief is completed, an Internal Brief document needs completing.  The Internal brief is slightly different because depending on the Internal Department, the information required is different.  So I thought I would create a generic table:

```
Internal_Brief
id  int(10) auto increment PK
project_id  int(10) (should be linked to Project)
internalDepartment  varchar(255)
```

And then somehow link another table to it.

```
Internal_Brief_Department
id  int(10) auto increment PK
internal_brief_id   int(10) (should be linked to Internal Brief)
someDate    varchar(255)
```

Somehow, these then all need linking to a Projects table.

In more of a story form, a client can have many projects.  A project can consist of one to many documents.  Each document requires its own information.  And that’s as far as my story seems to go.

Really I was looking for a bit of advice on how I can design the database according to what I have mentioned above?

Comment: This might be better asked in http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @petethepagan-gerbil On Code Review, the OP would have to show the actual code to create the database, not just the architecture/design of it. As written, this question would be off-topic on CR.

Comment: OK, thanks - I've never visited there, I just see it come up on the sidebar from time to time.